# Create a thermally homogeneous container

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics

I want to create a closed container where I will put 12 temperature sensors for a project in my company. I'm a software engineer and I have to deal with this project so I need help because I'm not good at thermal.

This container will look like a pan of 30 cm diameter. There will be one hot point at the bottom of the container to heat the inside of the container. What can I put in the container to have a homogeneous environment without overpressure; water, oil, sand or something else?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Engineering.SE! It would help a lot if you specified which temperature you are aiming for. Besides elaborate a bit more on homogeneous environment. Without any kind of flow / stirring inside the container there will be always a gradient in temperature from my understanding.

Comment: If you have a fluid in the container, continuous stirring will even out temperature.

Comment: In my project I will use one solar barbecue to concentrate sunbeam to heat the container. This solar barbecue: [link](http://www.focalis.net/solario-cooker/11-four-solaire-solario.html)

Comment: So there will be a hot point of 1000°C in the center of the container when there is a bright sun. Then a gradient of temperature from the center to the border of the container. This heat will transfer to the liquid or the other thing inside the container and the thing that I want to define is: "What is the best structure of the container to permit the liquid to have an homogenous temperature ? Double wall ? Further layout in the container ? Use sand instead of liquid to be more homogenous ?"

Comment: Either I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve or you still left open some crucial parts. Is it possible for you to stir the liquid? What you actually want to make sure is that there is no (or little to be accurate) heat transfer with the environment? What material is the container?

Comment: @EdelMartin The best way to get a uniform heat in the situation you are describing is to move the pan towards or away from the focus of the solar cooker until the light evenly illuminates the entire pan.  Concentrating it to a tiny spot just to spread the heat out can only be less efficient.

Comment: This seems a lot like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  And at this point, it's unlikely that you're going to get answers that address your actual problem.  Would you consider [edit]ing your question to provide more detail about what you're actually attempting to do and the current approach you think that will solve that problem?

Comment: @idkfa I don't want to stir the liquid in my container because it's not easy to do in my situation. Yes the thing I want to do is to heat the inside of my container, but I also want to have an homogenous temperature because I want all my temperature sensors to measure the same temperature. The container will be made of metal

Comment: @edelmartin Is it important that the temperature is homogeneous or do you just want to measure the same temperature everywhere? I'm thinking maybe there is a way of modelling the temperature gradient inside your container and offset the sensor's readings accordingly.